# What is the difference between save and saveAll function in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

can any one give example please

Answer (score 8):

`save` is used to simply save a model:

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
    (
        [fieldname1] => 'value'
        [fieldname2] => 'value'
    )
)
```

Assuming the above information was stored in an array called $data, one would call

```
$this->ModelName->save($data);
```

in order to INSERT a record into the model's table (if `id` field is not specified) or UPDATE a record of the model's table (if `id` field is specified).

`saveAll` is used to:

**Save multiple records of a model**

```
Array
(
    [Article] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => title 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => title 2
        )
    )
)
```

So, you may save many models at the same time instead of looping and using `save()` each time.

**Save related records of a model**

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
    (
        [username] => billy
    )
    [Profile] => Array
    (
        [sex] => Male
        [occupation] => Programmer
    )
)
```

This would save both `User` and `Profile` models at the same time. Otherwise, you would have to call `save()` for `User` first, obtain the `id` of the newly saved user and then save `Profile` with `user_id` set to the obtained `id`.

Examples taken straight from [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html).

Answer (score 1):

saveAll saves all model data in a form, whereas save only saves one. So you would use save to save a single value, while saveAll basically saves you the trouble of using a loop for save.

Answer (score 1):

As of Cake 2.0

> **save** Saves model data (based on white-list, if supplied) to the
>   database. By default, validation occurs before save.
>
> **saveAll** Saves multiple individual records for a single model; Also works with a single record, as well as all its associated records.