# What's the difference between ->save() and ->saveAll() in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between save and saveAll function in cakephp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516481/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-saveall-function-in-cakephp)

```
 66 if (!empty($this->data)) {
 67             $count = 1;
 68             foreach($this->data['Images'] as $entry){
 69                 $file_name = "file" . $count;      
 70                 if ($data_s = $this->Uploader->upload($file_name)) {    
 71                  $this->Image->saveAll($data_s);
 72                  }
 73                  $count++;
 74              }
 75             
 76             }
```

$data_s is an array of different info and each time I would use save() but it would only save 1 array from that whole foreach loop in the database. When I have used saveAll(), it saved all the entries from all the arrays.

I am kind of confused about the difference between save() and saveAll() and why it works that way?

Comment: A similar question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516481/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-saveall-function-in-cakephp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please [read the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data). `save` saves *one* record and `saveAll` saves either *many* records or the primary record and all associated records, depending on the data you give it. Also heed this notice from before-linked manual:

> When calling `save` in a loop, don't forget to call `create()`.

Comment: Thanks. I have read the documentation but I am still a bit confused. Is there a big difference if I do saveAll or save with create in the loop?